# Search for field contents contained in other records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list table having over 200,000 rows with city column. Assume that it contains following data:

```
rowid    city 
1        Toronto 
2        Milton
3        Hamilton
4        Delhi
5        New Delhi 
6        Markham
```

I want to find all records where the city is contained in another row, e.g. Milton (row 2) is contained in Hamilton (row 3) and Delhi (row 4) is contained in New Delhi (row 5). I expect the following output:

```
rowid   city   rowid2   city2
2       Milton   3      Hamilton
4       Delhi    5      New Delhi
```

Can a single query get the output I am looking for?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume table name is 'cities'. Following SQL query should work:

```
select
  c2.rowid, c2.city, c1.rowid, c1.city
from
  cities c1
inner join
  cities c2
    on instr(c1.city,c2.city)
    and c1.rowid != c2.rowid
```

Comment: Great. Simple solution. Thanks.